# How to enable access to a closed (private) wiki to a crawler?

Tags: web-crawler, mediawiki, user-permissions

I need to provide access to a private wiki to a crawler.

The wiki is closed to all anonymous users - you have to log in in order to see the contents, but I need to provide a single crawler (identified by a user-agent string and a single IP) full access so the contents can be indexed. It's an internal crawler so access to its resources will only be available upon successful login.

Any suggestions on how to enable access to a single client (and not user, since a crawler is not able to log itself into the wiki)?

Comment: why are you using a crawler? Why not use the default search or Lucene?

Comment: Because the Wiki is only part of Intranet. What I want to achieve is across-the-board search. We are currently using Lucene search plugin for Wiki, but there are several areas on the Intranet that need to be searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually is a solution to this problem.
As I mentioned a crawler will be using a specific IP and it will only be the crawler to use it. So quick and dirty but still a civilised way to do it is:

```
$crawler_ip = '1.2.3.4';
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $crawler_ip ) {
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
}
```

Simple, huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database you can use a database crawler in a system like solar to do this for you.

Comment: I am using Solr indeed but I am only following tutorials found on web so will need to find more about how database crawling can be done with it. I use Nutch to crawl pages. Not completely understanding the whole philosophy of it yet as I only began playing with it so I need to read up a lot more about it.

Comment: This really sounds like the approach you want to use since you've decided that you can't log it in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom usergroup for your crawler, let's say we call it 'crawler'. Since it has to login anyway that'd be the easiest solution.

Just give it read permissions like this:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']    = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['crawler']['read']    = true;
```

Reference: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#Changing_group_permissions

*edit* Hmm wait, I misread. The crawler is probably not a logged-in account right? Hold on, checking if you can set permissions to an IP.

Comment: Will this help? Crawler is not able to log in. How MediaWiki will identify the crawler and assign it to 'crawler' group?

Comment: No sorry, I can't figure out a way to do this without logging in.., except actually crawling the database instead of the pages